# Why is my sprite sheet animation sliding?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

Trying to implement a sprite sheet animation via css. I have followed this example

https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/zxXrzP

However, my animation is sliding vertically and I can not understand why. Any input appreciated.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  margin: -10% auto 0 auto;
  /* positioning tweak */
}

.parent:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 61.37%;
}

.ryu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url("http://dev.froststudio.se/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/frostcell_v03.png");
  background-size: 100%;
  animation: sprite 4s steps(79) forwards;
}

@keyframes sprite {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0%;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 100%;
  }
}
```

http://dev.froststudio.se

Cheers,

Comment: Please post your code here. Not only e reference to your site

Comment: Post edited to contain code. Cheers.

Comment: @cathor, I see two possible causes. 1) are there exactly 79 image frames? 2) maybe the `to {background-position: 0 100%;}` should only be moved to the total height (100%) - the height of a frame?

Comment: @Uchendu Thanks, the frame count is actually 80 but setting it to 80 makes it even worse, like its rolling. Can try to adjust the other parameter but the example is using 100% and its working. Cheers,

Comment: @cathor, Has each frame of your sprite the same height? Because the problem comes from a small offset somewhere on each frame of the animation. To make this visible, you can set `to {background-position: 0 100.1%;}`. Where exactly the problem is coming from is difficult to say. I'd recommend you to regenerate the sprite (maybe using another service this time), in order to assure proper spacing. Another source for the error could be that already in the animation itself, there is a vertical sliding